# What is the largest number of elements of $\{\sin\alpha\cos\beta,\sin\beta\cos\gamma,\sin\gamma\cos\alpha\}$ (all angles acute) that can exceed $1/2$?

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ be three arbitrary **acute** angles. Let $n$ be the number of elements larger than $1/2$ in $\{\sin\alpha\cos\beta,\sin\beta\cos\gamma,\sin\gamma\cos\alpha\}$. What is the largest possible n?

Well all I can do is to use the identity $$2\sin\alpha\cos\beta=\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\sin(\alpha-\beta)$$
to break them apart. But then I have no idea to figure out the relation of these three terms.

Comment: Can you find a set of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ where one of products is larger than $1/2$? How about two? All three?

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the product of all three elements?

Comment: @Troposphere Currently I can only find when one is larger than $1/2$. That is $45°, 45°, 50°$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if $\sin\alpha\cos\beta>\frac12$ then $\frac12\sin(\alpha+\beta)+\frac12\sin(\alpha-\beta)>\frac12$

However, $\frac12\sin(\alpha+\beta)\leq\frac12$, so this is only possible if $\sin(\alpha-\beta)>0$

Since your angles are acute, this means you need $\alpha-\beta>0$.

Given three arbitrary acute angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, at most two of $\alpha-\beta$, $\beta-\gamma$ and $\gamma-\alpha$ can be positive, so the answer is $n\leq2$.

To show $n=2$, you can demonstrate the existence of such an $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Try some angles near $\frac\pi4=45^\circ$.